# Why does my question keep getting deleted even though it is relevant?

Tags: discussion, bug

I have a question about my Law Stack Exchange post: [illegal to taunt neighbor with their impending death by covid-19?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50097/illegal-to-taunt-neighbor-with-their-impending-death-by-covid-19)

I asked a question at https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50097/illegal-to-taunt-neighbor-with-their-impending-death-by-covid-19 and it got deleted immediately. The moderator, @Pat W. did actually give a partial answer to the question but then deleted it. I had previously asked the question at another link which the same moderator had also deleted.

The question is very specifically about potential legal consequences for an action, both from the court and my apartment complex. Why is this question being forbidden? Why is it being deleted without any information about what is wrong with the question or how to make it salvageable? This is very rude to simply quash a question that is being asked in good faith. I'd be happy to modify my question if there is something about it which makes it unfit for this site. I deserve to be told how to make my question acceptable to the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question, and the ensuing discussion, asked how to harass your neighbor in a manner that stops short of criminal behavior.

Apart from being a request for personalized legal advice, it isn't nice, likely violates the [Code of Conduct](https://law.stackexchange.com/conduct), and isn't in keeping with the purpose of the site. To be more direct: the site isn't interested in facilitating harassment, intimidation, or bullying.

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining your reasoning, @Pat W.  I retract my remarks against you.  Do remember to explain your decisions in the future and not just quash people with no explanation.  You have a reason my question was not appropriate, and that is fine.  What wasn't fine was not giving me any feedback on what was wrong.  Please remember this in the future when moderating people.  Good day.

Comment: @notinterpersonal there is no requirement on anyone to explain their voting reasons - up, down or close. If people do give feedback, it's a bonus, if they don't it is not appropriate to criticise them.

Answer (score 4):

When a moderator deletes a question, you are not supposed to avoid that deletion by re-posting. Instead, you should post a question on Meta, focusing on the core question about the original question. I can only conjecture about the specific reasons that the moderator had in mind; I conjecture that it is in the area "general well-being of Law SE". You are clearly asking for legal advice about the possibility of committing a crime. You question is unambiguously about a personal (il)legal need, not about principles of the law. The correct way to get personal legal advice is to hire an attorney. LSE is explicitly not intended for getting free legal advice, and is not designed to aid in the commission of a crime. Your question lacks the dispassionate generality that distinguishes your question from a general and acceptable question on LSE.

Comment: Furthermore, you are wrong: I am not asking about how to commit a crime.  I am specifically trying to AVOID committing a crime.  I am intending to take action against my neighbor, and I am trying to make SURE that my action will not get me in trouble.